# Trying to Make the Simplest OpenID using DotNetOpenAuth Login in asp.net

Tags: dotnetopenauth

I've downloaded the Visual Studio 2010 Template associated with the http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/.  I can get that to work as advertised.  I am not starting a project from scratch and I don't want to put a lot of time into integrating all the web.config, handlers, etc. into my application to get OpenID working for me.  The doc says that I should be able to make a one line implementation using a button and a user control.  I believe I have done that and I get an error.

Here is what I've done.

1. Create empty asp.net web project
2. Add DotNetOpenAuth.dll to bin and reference it
3. Add user control registration to top of page
4. Create Button on page that calls user control.

When I run it and press the button, I get:

***"Precondition failed: this.Identifier != null No identifier has been set."***

I know there must be more to it than this, but I just don't get it.  Can someone explain further what I need to do?

Thanks,

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="DotNetOpenAuth" Namespace="DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty" TagPrefix="rp" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<script runat="server">

    protected void LoginId_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenIdTextBox1.LogOn();
    }
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:Button ID="LoginId" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="LoginId_Click" />

      <rp:OpenIdTextBox ID="OpenIdTextBox1" runat="server" />

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you using a regular button and an `rp:OpenIdTextBox` instead of just an `rp:OpenIdLogin`? Also what is the stacktrace for the error you're getting?

Answer (score 1):

You you actually typing an identifier in the box before clicking the button?  You must.

And you can avoid the nasty error for people who forget to type an identifier by adding a `RequiredFieldValidator` control that points to the text box and then checking that `if (Page.IsValid)` in your button's click handler before calling `LogOn`.

Hopefully this helps.  Have you considered using the `OpenIdLogin` control?  If you're shooting for easiest to add, that's the easiest, as you don't have any code at all -- just the one tag.

Also, be sure to add `ValidateRequest="false"` to your `<%@ Page %>` tag at the top of your login page. Otherwise your users will see occasional random failures because ASP.NET incorrectly interprets some OpenID authentication responses to be attacks.
So for example, if the top line of your .aspx was:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="True" CodeBehind="login.aspx.cs" Inherits="OpenIdRelyingPartyWebForms.login" %>
```

Make it

```
<%@ Page ValidateRequest="false" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="True" CodeBehind="login.aspx.cs" Inherits="OpenIdRelyingPartyWebForms.login" %>
```

Comment: can you elaborate on the ValidateRequest bit, or provide a link? Sounds like something I need to know. ;)

Comment: @jalf, I've enhanced my answer.

Comment: "ASP.NET incorrectly interprets some OpenID authentication responses to be attacks" - could you explain this in a little more detail.  Why would ASP.NET do that?

Comment: There are script injection attacks that most sites are vulnerable to unless they actively sanitize their input from the client. Since most folks aren't aware of it, ASP.NET defaults to doing some of this for you. But they do it by looking for troublesome character patterns like `<` and `>` characters, which are legitimately found in OpenID messages.